# My xml won't validate against my schema

Tags: xsd

I have just made my first attempt at XSD.

When I try and validate my XML against my XSD, I get the error:
Cannot find the declaration of element 'linkage'.

Below I give my XSD and a cut down version of my XML. I've tried adding a namespace qualifier to the top element in my XML and also to every element (changing the XSD to qualified) and it did not help. I'm obviously making a basic mistake. As I'm new to XSD, if you could include what I need to change in my XML and/or XSD I would be very grateful.

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.stephenwaring.me.uk/android/nestedsettings"
    xmlns="http://www.stephenwaring.me.uk/android/nestedsettings"
    elementFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="linkage">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="preference-screen" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="parent" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="child" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:token" use="required" />
                                                <xs:attribute name="reformat" type="xs:boolean" />
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attributeGroup ref="keyed" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="preference-screen" type="xs:token" use="required" />
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attributeGroup ref="keyed"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="defaults"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:attributeGroup name="defaults">
        <xs:attribute name="html" type="xs:boolean" />
        <xs:attribute name="prefix" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="suffix" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="separator" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="reformat" type="xs:boolean" />
        <xs:attribute name="shaddow" type="xs:boolean" />   
        <xs:attribute name="child-summary" type="xs:boolean" /> 
        <xs:attribute name="shadow-separator" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:attributeGroup>
    <xs:attributeGroup name="keyed">
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="defaults" />
        <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:token" use="required" />
    </xs:attributeGroup>
</xs:schema>
```

Cut down XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<linkage
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://stevewaring.me.uk/android/nestedsettings nestedsettings.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.stevewaring.me.uk">
    <preference-screen
        key="preferences1">
        <parent
            key="prefFruit"
            preference-screen="preferences2">
            <child key="prefFruit1"/>
            <child key="prefFruit2"/>
        </parent>
    </preference-screen>
</linkage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSD defines elements in http://www.stephenwaring.me.uk/android/nestedsettings whereas your document element is in http://www.stevewaring.me.uk. Make them to agree, one way or the other, and it should take care of the error you're having.

I've added a fixed XML, there's another issue related to use of unqualified elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<linkage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.stephenwaring.me.uk/android/nestedsettings nestedsettings.xsd" xmlns="http://www.stephenwaring.me.uk/android/nestedsettings">
    <preference-screen xmlns="" key="preferences1">
        <parent key="prefFruit" preference-screen="preferences2">
            <child key="prefFruit1"/>
            <child key="prefFruit2"/>
        </parent>
    </preference-screen>
</linkage>
```